# SVN Console .NET error

Tags: .net, svn, console, cmd

Am having an issue with SVN.

I am creating an application in .NET 4 forms to automate a few things - one thing which i seem to be having issues with is checking out SVN.

```
        String RepositoryLocation = GetRepositoryPath();
        String ProjectLocation = GetProjectPath();

        RepositoryLocation = "\"file:///" + RepositoryLocation + "\"";
        ProjectLocation = "\"" + ProjectLocation + "\"";

        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo();

        ps.FileName = _svnDirectory + "svn.exe";
        ps.Arguments = @"checkout -r HEAD " + RepositoryLocation + " " + ProjectLocation;
        ps.UseShellExecute = false;
        ps.RedirectStandardError = true;

        p.StartInfo = ps;
        p.Start();

        if (waitForExit == true)
        {
            p.WaitForExit();
        }

        //  test for an error
        String error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        p.Close();
```

this here spits out an error message "svn: e720002: write error: the system cannot find the file specified".

It seems to create the .svn hidden folder in the project folder fine - but the error still shows.

This installation of SVN was installed with the TortoiseSVN client.

SVN version 1.7.4
TortoiseSVN version 1.7.6 (probably not needed)

UPDATE:

The command in set to the args is:

"checkout \"file:///C:/test/test client/repositories/test project/\" \"C:/test/test client/test project/\""

(note the \" escaping the quote allows for spaces in the directory path)

Comment: did you try resulted command in console svn-client?

Comment: It works perfectly, which leads me to believe it maybe a quotes issue or something? Or possibly a permissions issue?

Comment: Not permissions most probably

Comment: In the IDE, when you hover over ps.Arguments, does the value look correct?

Comment: Have updated with the value of the Arguments, it looks fine to me and when I paste this into CMD it works fine - am thinking svn may get this error but for some reason decides not to show it?

Comment: How can that be the Arguments parameter when -r HEAD is specified? Where did that go?

Comment: Sorry I have changed to code since Monday trying to get it working. The -r HEAD means it is checking out the head. weather this is there or not is inconsequential. for your benefit - "checkout -r HEAD \"file:///C:/test/test client/repositories/test project/\" \"C:/test/test client/test project/\""

Comment: One thing that might be different between your code and executing it in a console might be the working directory. While it shouldn't be a problem in this case, it might be worth trying to set it explicitely. Also try simplifying your code by not redirecting STDERR. Have you tried a .bat executing the same command and putting it in the same directory as your .exe?

Comment: Also try using a path without any spaces or special characters to see if it's some problem with quoting. In this case you could try temporarily removing the added " characters to see if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the exact same problem with you.  What I did is to ignore any error message from svn and run 'svn status' command at the end. if it returns empty string, it means that everything is ok. If not, then there is a real problem.

Comment: Even though it's a workaround it will fix the problem - thanks :) I've just been ignoring the error message for now.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran your exact code with the following assumptions. It worked fine. I also created the repository in the exact directory and the working copy in the exact directory as you specified.

I made sure that the checkout was good by doing an `svn update`. That output is below too.

Please make sure that all the things below are exactly what you're doing/returning. If anything is different, that is possibly the culprit. If everything is identical, you are probably experiencing permission issues. Can you try running the process as administrator if you have UAC on by running Visual Studio as administrator?

**SVN Update**

```
C:\test\test client\test project>svn update
Updating '.':
At revision 0.
```

**Folder Structure**

```
C:\
  - test
    - test client
      - test project
      - repositories
        - test project
```

**Code**

```
private const string _svnDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\";

private static String GetRepositoryPath()
{
    return @"C:/test/test client/repositories/test project/";
}

private static String GetProjectPath()
{
    return @"C:/test/test client/test project/";
}
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your response. It looks exactly the same as mine. however I am still getting the error.
Perhaps I should have mentioned this earlier, but the following code after the p.start(); is

           if (waitForExit == true)
            {
                p.WaitForExit();
            }

            //  test for an error
            String error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            p.Close();

where error is where i am reading the error from.

I have updated the original question with this.

Comment: Rats. I'm not sure what it could be, but I duplicated your code, and added the same ReadToEnd(), and I didn't get the error on my end, so it must be system-specific; not SVN specific. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Chris, I am not sure, my system config is Windows 7 and I am an administrator on this machine :( (doing a trial with visual studio running as administrator yesterday didn't work either)

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be when you read the StandardError. 
You should put the call to `p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` before the `p.WaitForExit();`
See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandarderror.aspx)

Also I would recommend the excellent [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/) library for a C# interface to SVN that does not use the external command line client.

Comment: +1. Not relying on the commandline client but a library is a much better thing to do (at least I frequently can't use the commandline client due to its braindead handling of non-ASCII filenames).

Comment: I previously had it before the WaitForExit and was testing it out after, but makes no difference (I have moved it back). SharpSVN looks great however for this particular task I cannot justify moving it to SharpSVN, I may as well just ignore the error. Any other ideas? :)